# Past Tense after "if"

Tags: tenses, past-tense, conditionals, passive-voice, would

> “A letter?” repeated Professor McGonagall faintly, sitting back down on the wall. “Really, Dumbledore, you think you can explain all this in a letter? These people will never understand him! He’ll be famous—a legend—I wouldn’t be surprised if today was known as Harry Potter day in the future—there will be books written about Harry—every child in our world will know his name!”

Why do we use Past Tense in "if today was known"?

Comment: Perhaps Professor McGonagall meant to use a subjunctive (describing a hypothetical situation) ... but pedantically that should be "if today were known".

Comment: I think also that "if today will be known" would also make sense. It matches with "there will be books written".

Comment: _Was_ is more comfortable and shorter and easier to say than _were_ and it's also grammatical and not pedantic.

Comment: The subjunctive is frequently replaced with the past tense in casual speech. "I'd eat if I was hungry."

Comment: @Кирилл Мир Might it be more simple if instead of 'was', she'd said 'if today "were" known as Harry Potter day in the future"?